# Multiple txt files as separate rows in a csv file without breaking into lines (in pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text, export-to-csv

I have many txt files (which have been converted from pdf) in a folder. I want to create a csv/excel dataset where each text file will become a row. Right now I am opening the files in `pandas dataframe` and then trying to save it to a `csv` file. When I print the `dataframe`, I get one row per txt file. However, when saving to `csv` file, the texts get broken and create multiple rows/lines for each txt file rather than just one row. Do you know how I can solve this problem? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Following is the code I am using now.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "K:\\text_all", "*.txt"))

corpus = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path, encoding="latin-1") as f_input:
        corpus.append(f_input.read())

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':corpus})
print (df)

df.to_csv('K:\\out.csv')
```

**Update**

If this solution is not possible it would be also helpful to transform the data a bit in `pandas dataframe`. I want to create a column with the name of txt files, that is, the name of each txt file in the folder will become the identifier of the respective text file. I will then save it to `tsv` format so that the lines do not get separated because of `comma`, as suggested by someone here.

I need something like following.

```
identifier       col
txt1             example text in this file
txt2             second example text in this file
...
txtn             final example text in this file
```

Comment: The text in your files have `,`(comma). Saving as CSV depends on that as the separator. So wherever there's a comma you'll have a break. Try TSV(Tab-separated values) `df.to_csv('K:\\out.tsv', sep='\t')`.

Comment: Thanks @Vishnudev. The problem is I lose text identifier then as I wanted to edit it manually to create a column to identify texts. Is there any way I can convert a tsv file into csv then? 
Or, alternatively, is it possible to create a column in `dataframe` by the name of text files, that is, `text1` `text2` `text3` etc. Sorry, if it is obscure I am happy to explain more.

Comment: You need to elaborate more with an example in your question @crackers.

Comment: I have tried this: `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`. Seems not to be working. 
I have included a further explanation of what I was explaining earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import csv
df.to_csv('K:\\out.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```